# GoogleMaps apiv3 Events - addListener and addDomListener not working the same way?

Tags: events, google-maps-api-3, listener, polygon

I'm having trouble trying to add a polygon to the map by clicking something outside of the map area, e.g. a text link on the same page as the map.

I can add the polygon by clicking on the map via the addListener method but the same code with `addDomListener` doesn't work. Was wondering if anyone knows how to do this correctly?

My code that is not working (i get the alert test so the listener is working but the polygon is not added to the map):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('thediv'), 'click',function (event){
    drawPolygon();
    alert("test");
});
```

The code that is working but not what I want (polygon is drawn and alert test is received):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click',function (event){
    drawPolygon();
    alert("test");
});
```

and the drawPolygon code which works:

```
function drawPolygon(){
var bermudaTriangle;
var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
];

  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: triangleCoords,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});

bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to also include your HTML?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here it is:

`code`<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>   
  <div id="thediv"><a href="/" onlcick="drawPolygon()" id="thelink">test</a></div>
</body>`/code`